# Flutter webRTC video/audio calls terminates on back button tap

Tags: flutter, dart, calling-convention, videocall, flutter-webrtc

I have used [flutter_webrtc][1] for video and audio calls in my application. I have implemented it successfully. And everything is going well but in one case I am facing a problem with one functionality like WhatsApp.

For ex:
If 2 people making a P2P cal at that time one of the users presses the back button at that time the call gets terminated but it should not be like that. the call should be active and minimized form just like in WhatsApp we have like, if one user presses the back button it will go to the chat screen but call remains the active.

I have tried to find some solution for this feature but not getting the desired outcome. And flutter_webrtc itself not having the functionality.

So, if someone did the same thing just please let me know and help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

[1]: git: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc